# How to add extra rows on FireFox? How to change window title on Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I've been using Chrome and I'm learning to use Firefox recently.

I notice as I download more and more add-ons, it's very hard for me to see the website address.
I can easily change size of address bar on Chrome by dragging, but I'm not able to easily change address size on Firefox.

Although I can hide some add-ons by moving it to overflow menu, many icons are actually useful for my browsing experience and it would be extremely tedious to constantly click the overflow buttons to use some add-ons.

I'm wondering is there a way to customize Firefox by adding an extra row specifically for add-ons? The site information button constantly takes too much space on address bar and I can't tell what web address I'm on. So the best solution would be allocating address bar on the entire row, and then allocate add-ons on the other row below it.

If it's not possible, is it possible to show website address on title bar?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 thanks for your answer with references, I'm thinking to change the window title as the workaround for now

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way to solve the problem is to display website address on the title bar

1. Enable title bar by right click on Firefox→customize→check title bar
2. Install Custom [Titlebar Textby by Hrvoje Šolc](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-titlebar-text/?src=search).

Known Problem: This add-ons does not work on some pages, such as official Firefox pages, YouTube, ...